# How to dynamically chain when conditions in Pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

#### Context

A dataframe should have the `category` column, which is based on a set of fixed rules. The set of rules becomes quite large.

#### Question

Is there a way to use a list of tuples (see example below) to dynamically chain the `when` conditions to achieve the same result as hard coded solution at the bottom.

```py
# Potential list of rule definitions
category_rules = [
    ('A', 8, 'small'),
    ('A', 30, 'large'),
    ('B', 5, 'small'),
    # Group, size smaller value --> Category
    # and so on ... e.g.,
]
```

#### Example

Here is a toy example for reproducibility. A dataframe consisting of groups and ids should have the column `category` added, which depends on the content of the `group` column. The list of rules is shown in the section above.

Input data

```py
data = [('A', '45345', 5), ('C', '55345', 5), ('A', '35345', 10), ('B', '65345', 4)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['group', 'id', 'size'])
```

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|group|   id| size|
+-----+-----+-----+
|    A|45345|    5|
|    C|55345|    5|
|    A|35345|   10|
|    B|65345|    4|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Hard coded solution

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    'category',
    F.when(
        (F.col('group') == 'A')
        & (F.col('size') < 8),
        F.lit('small')
    ).when(
        (F.col('group') == 'A')
        & (F.col('size') < 30),
        F.lit('large')
    ).when(
        (F.col('group') == 'B')
        & (F.col('size') < 5),
        F.lit('small')
    ).otherwise(
        F.lit('unkown')
    )
)
```

```py
+-----+-----+----+--------+
|group|   id|size|category|
+-----+-----+----+--------+
|    A|45345|   5|   small|
|    C|55345|   5|  unkown|
|    A|35345|  10|   large|
|    B|65345|   4|   small|
+-----+-----+----+--------+
```

[Edit 1] Add more complex conditions to explain why chaining is needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution based on the dataframe api:

```python
cond = F.when(F.col('group') == category_rules[0][0], F.lit(category_rules[0][1]))
for c in category_rules[1:]:
    cond = cond.when(F.col('group') == c[0], F.lit(c[1]))
cond = cond.otherwise('unknown')

df.withColumn("category", cond).show()
```

Comment: Superb use of `cond = cond.when(...)` to create the chain.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string interpolation to create an expression such as:

```py
CASE 
   WHEN (group = 'A') THEN 'small' 
   WHEN (group = 'B') THEN 'large'
   ELSE 'unkown'
END
```

And then use it in Spark expression:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

data = [('A', '45345'), ('C', '55345'), ('A', '35345'), ('B', '65345')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['group', 'id'])

category_rules = [('A', 'small'), ('B', 'large')]

when_cases = [f"WHEN (group = '{r[0]}') THEN '{r[1]}'" for r in category_rules]

rules_expr = "CASE " + " ".join(when_cases) + " ELSE 'unkown' END"
# CASE WHEN (group = 'A') THEN 'small' WHEN (group = 'B') THEN 'large' ELSE 'unkown' END

df.withColumn('category', expr(rules_expr)).show()

# +-----+-----+--------+
# |group|   id|category|
# +-----+-----+--------+
# |    A|45345|   small|
# |    C|55345|  unkown|
# |    A|35345|   small|
# |    B|65345|   large|
# +-----+-----+--------+
```

Comment: That should also work for multiple complex conditions as the updated question shows. 
As this is basically SQL, I am wondering if you see any security issues with the proposed solution, e.g., SQL injections?

Comment: SQL injections in your big data storage? I think this is difficult but definitely not impossible. Although it depends on how you generate the category_rules list since this is the only source of any potential injection. It also supports complex conditions yes

Answer (score 1):

I hope this solution fits you:

Create a new dataframe with the list of tuples you define with the columns 'group' and 'category':
category_rules = [('A', 'small'),('B', 'large'), etc]
This will be your 'lookup_dataframe'

```
lookup_df = spark.createDataFrame(category_rules , ['group', 'category'])
```

Then you can left join both dataframes on the column 'group', so for every row with a group value will get the category value in the column you joined from the lookup_df.

```
df = df.join(lookup_dataframe, ['group'], 'left')
```

By making a left join, if there is a group value in your df (on the right side) that´s not included in the lookup_df, like 'C', it will have a null value.

Comment: Thanks. That would be a basic solution. But I am wondering how you would do this if there would be a more complex set of conditions. E.g., Besides the `group` some numeric value needs to match a set of dependent conditions. Will update the question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functional way of chaining the conditions:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [('A', '45345', 5), ('C', '55345', 5), ('A', '35345', 10), ('B', '65345', 4)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['group', 'id', 'size'])

category_rules = [
    ('A', 8, 'small'),
    ('A', 30, 'large'),
    ('B', 5, 'small'),
    # Group, size smaller value --> Category
    # and so on ... e.g.,
]


def chain_conditions(acc: Column | None, x: tuple):
    if acc is None:
        return F.when(F.col('group') == x[0], x[-1])
    else:
        return acc.when(F.col('group') == x[0], x[-1])


category = reduce(chain_conditions, category_rules, None)
category = category.otherwise('unknown')

df.withColumn('category', category).show(10, False)

# +-----+-----+----+--------+
# |group|id   |size|category|
# +-----+-----+----+--------+
# |A    |45345|5   |small   |
# |C    |55345|5   |unknown |
# |A    |35345|10  |small   |
# |B    |65345|4   |small   |
# +-----+-----+----+--------+
```