# How to use constant values in dynamic spark sql query

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, pyspark

I have a dictionary as below

```
city = {"AP":"VIZAG", "TELANGANA":"HYDERABAD"}
```

and also I have a list which I need to loop for all state tables as below

```
states = ['AP','HYDERABAD']

for st in states:
 df = spark.sql(f"""select * from {st} where city = {city}["{st}"]""")
```

In above df I am trying to filter city based on dictionary value as per state. But I am not able to do it

Comment: `'{city[st]}'` not `{city}["{st}"]`

Answer (score 0):

#### New answer

By combining two filter conditions you can do the expected filtering.

```py
selected_city = 'AP'
df = df.filter(
    (F.col('city') == selected_city)
    & (F.col('state') == cities[selected_city])
)
```

#### Old answer

It is a simple change: You can use `isin` to filter a column based on a list [[Docs]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isin).

```py
cities = list(city.keys())

df = df.filter(F.col('city').isin(cities))
```

If you want to construct more complex conditions based on a dictionary see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64375061/how-to-dynamically-chain-when-conditions-in-pyspark).

[Edit] Updated answer based on OPs comment. Will leave the old one in there for completeness.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But I need to filter only if state='AP' then city should filter with'VIZAG' which is the dictionary value for AP

Comment: Cool. Just edited the answer, hope I understood what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for your help