# Pivot data in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to pivot data based on the column name. Column name before `_` will become provider name in output, and the remaining part of that column name becomes the new column name. This is just an example as the real time scenario is much more complicated than this (some columns are present only for one provider).

Also we have some columns which are only specific to one provider and i'm wondering how to keep value as `null` for other provider

Desired Output is given as result. Please help in resolving this .

````
import sys,os
import concurrent.futures
from concurrent.futures import *
import boto3
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.context import SparkConf
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

from pyspark.sql import DataFrame


###############################

class JobBase(object):
    spark=None
    def __start_spark_glue_context(self):
        conf = SparkConf().setAppName("python_thread")
        self.sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
        self.glueContext = GlueContext(self.sc)
        self.spark = self.glueContext.spark_session

    def execute(self):
        self.__start_spark_glue_context()
        new_dict={}
        print('hello')
        # schema = StructType([ \
        # StructField("curr_col1",StringType(),True), \
        # StructField("curr_col2",StringType(),True), \
        # ])
        d = [{"curr_col1": '75757', "curr_col2": "fgsjdfd"}]
        
        d = [{"v1_ind": 'A', "v1_rev": 23,"v2_ind": 'b', "v2_rev": 44}]

      
        df = self.spark.createDataFrame(data=d)
     
        df.show()        
        
def main():
    job = JobBase()
    job.execute() 
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

+------+------+------+------+
|v1_ind|v1_rev|v2_ind|v2_rev|
+------+------+------+------+
|     A|    23|     b|    44|
+------+------+------+------+

required output 

+---+---+--------+
|Ind|Rev|provider|
+---+---+--------+
|  A| 23|      V1|
|  B| 44|      V2|
+---+---+--------+

    ```
````

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to handle all cases, you can generate the `stack` expression generically by processing the column list of your dataframe. This way, you can also insert a null value in case a column is not present for some providers.

```py
# getting the lists of providers and column names
providers = list(set(map(lambda s: s.split('_')[0], df.columns)))
names =  list(set(map(lambda s: s.split('_')[1], df.columns)))
# sorting them for reproducibility, this is optional
providers.sort()
names.sort()

# generating the list of columns to stack, handling missing columns
stack_cols = []
for provider in providers:
    for name in names:
        col_name = provider + '_' + name
        if col_name not in df.columns:
            stack_cols.append('null')
        else:
            stack_cols.append('string('+col_name+')')
    stack_cols.append("'"+provider+"'")

# wrapping everything up
stack_expr = "stack(" + str(len(providers)) + "," + ",".join(stack_cols) + ")"
alias = "(" + ",".join(names)+",provider)"
result = df.select(F.expr(stack_expr + " as " + alias))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `stack` function for this case and based on the [**dynamic column name values**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64375706/7632695) you can generate the provider names.

**`Example:`**

```
d = [{"v1_ind": 'A', "v1_rev": 23,"v2_ind": 'b', "v2_rev": 44}] 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=d)
df.select(expr("stack(2,v1_ind,string(v1_rev),'v1',v2_ind,string(v2_rev),'v2') as (ind,rev,provider)")).show(10,False)
#+---+---+--------+
#|ind|rev|provider|
#+---+---+--------+
#|A  |23 |v1      |
#|b  |44 |v2      |
#+---+---+--------+
```